# sass - Get attribute of selected element using scss

Tags: sass

I'm trying extract the background images of similar buttons into a sass map like the following:

```
$icons: (
  users: '../../assets/files/images/admin/navicon_users_unselected@2x.png',
  cms: '../../assets/files/images/admin/navicon_content_unselected@2x.png',
  rules: '../../assets/files/images/admin/navicon_rules_unselected@2x.png',
  data: '../../assets/files/images/admin/navicon_data_unselected@2x.png,',
  setting: '../../assets/files/images/admin/navicon_settings_unselected@2x.png',
  logout: '../../assets/files/images/admin/navicon_logout_unselected@2x.png'
);
```

Is there a way for me to dynamically generate styling for each of my buttons by accessing their `div#id` attribute and using that to access this hash?

My goal is to simplify my sytling to something that looks like the following:

```
div {
  background-image: url(map-get($icons, $this.id));
}
```

I'm looking for the correct syntax to replace `$this.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sass doesn't have a concept for `this`. But If you know all your button ids, you can put them in a map or a list and iterate. A list would be easier.
 [DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/c61eff2976f996d69df6690d2227f2c9)

#### Map

```
$icons: (
  users: '../../assets/files/images/admin/navicon_users_unselected@2x.png',
  cms: '../../assets/files/images/admin/navicon_content_unselected@2x.png',
  rules: '../../assets/files/images/admin/navicon_rules_unselected@2x.png',
  data: '../../assets/files/images/admin/navicon_data_unselected@2x.png,',
  setting: '../../assets/files/images/admin/navicon_settings_unselected@2x.png',
  logout: '../../assets/files/images/admin/navicon_logout_unselected@2x.png'
);

@each $key, $val in $icons {
  .#{$key} {
    background-image: url($val);
  }
}
```

#### List

```
$icon-list: users, cms, rules, data, setting, logout;

@each $key in $icon-list {
  ##{$key} {
    background-image: url('../../assets/files/images/admin/navicon_#{$key}_unselected@2x.png');
  }
}
```